# Error compiling GO project for windows using mingw32 on ubuntu

Tags: windows, go, cgo, mingw32

I am trying to build go for windows (CGO_ENABLED =1) using mingw32 on ubuntu but not able to compile the binary.

Error:
`/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -ldl: No such file or directory /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -ldl: No such file or directory collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Command used:
`GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc go build`

Comment: I wonder why `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld` is ever called: on my system (`linux/amd64` with Go 1.17.x) this program is never called when I build a cgo-enabled project. Anyway, such question is not fit for SO as it requires multiple backs-and-forths, so please consider posting a message to [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts) instead.